# Is there any way to open the CMD through teamcity so it will open and displayed on the desktop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, teamcity

I have a batch job that i want to deploy from Teamcity to several servers,
to access several servers i use Winexe tool.

the batch is running but i can't see the session because it's started from teamcity,
but i can see that its running when looking at the process list.

My issue is that sometimes this job is having some errors,
which are being displayed on the cmd window when i run it manualy 
but since i'm running it through TeamCity i can't see the CMD window so i can't see the error.

My question is:
Is there any way to open the CMD through teamcity  so it will open and displayed on the desktop when i access the server as the same user?

note: bare in mind that i need to deploy it to several servers so i can't install several
agents via ZIP File.

Comment: If you enable the `Allow service to interact with desktop` option for the Teamcity service on the build server it should allow the cmd window to appear, but it will appear the desktop of whoever is logged in at them time. You might want to see about having the output of the batch file redirected to a log somewhere instead.

Comment: teamcity agent run as a java process and not as a service

Comment: Those aren't mutually exclusive concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found kind of a work-around to solve this problem,
I created a schedule task in windows that will run my batch.

when creating this task you need to set those settings:

1.) Run as: the user name that TeamCity is logging in.

2.) check the Run only if logged on check box.

3.) in the security tab give the user you use full permitions.

In order to run the schedule task you need to run this batch script:

```
Schtasks.exe /Run /TN name_of_schedule_task
```